# JavaScript arguments array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I am new to JavaScript and came across this snippet:

```
function addSuffix()
{
    var sString= " ";
    for (var k=1, k<arguments.length; k++)
    {
         sString +=arguments[k] + arguments[0] + " " ;
    } 
    return sString;
 }

 console.info(addSuffix('s','bow','dog','kite'));
```

Can somebody explain. (I have read about java script and know abouts loops etc but this example confused me mainly because of the arguments array)

Comment: [MDN arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: ^^^ Is there anything specific in the documentation that you don't understand or you think is missing from the documentation? If so, please let us know. Please read the documentation *before* asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The **arguments** array is a way to pass "unlimited" values to a function, without having to specify every single one of them.

Think of it as a way to make a function recieve a non-specified number of values. In your example, it would be the same as saying:

```
function addSuffix(argument1, argument2, argument3)
{
    var sString = argument2+argument1+" "+argument3+argument1+" ";
    return sString;
 }
```

Because it starts from [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) (the second argument passed), then adds the first one again (arguments[0]) then a white space (" "). Then it repeats the process.

See more about this array at the [Mozilla Developer Network.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 0):

When a function is executed an arguments object is created. The arguments object has an array-like structure with an indexed property for each passed argument and a length property equal to the total number of parameters supplied by the caller.

Answer (score -1):

Variable Values After First Iteration of for loop:

### sString = "bows "

Variable Values After Second Iteration of for loop:

### sString = "bows dogs "

Variable Values After third Iteration of for loop:

### sString = "bows dogs kites "

---

Return: "bows dogs kites "

The return value from console.info is "bows dogs kites ".

The length of the arguments are 4. The for loop runs a total of 3 times. 
Each time it will add the element that is in the first position in the arguments array
and add it to the end of the string of the k-th element in the argument array. It keeps adding on to the sString.

Does this make sense?